# How can I download a torrent in reverse order of pieces?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, rtorrent, qbittorrent, ktorrent

I mean we have this option of downloading sequentially, and first-and-last pieces order.. but what I need is a last-piece-first order!

Any method that can achieve that?

Edit 1:
As to why I need it(for those who ask), I wish to download the same torrent, lets say 50gb, simultaneously in two halves, each on a different device, and then combine them using merge-torrent.

Merge-Torrent:
[Merging uncompleted torrent files](https://superuser.com/questions/289392/merging-uncompleted-torrent-files)
https://code.google.com/archive/p/mergetorrent/

This halves the time needed for downloading the entire file if we have two internet connections, two hotspots. And a device can use one at a time so the two devices.

Edit 2:
The question could go deeper: "How to download a specific range of pieces in a torrent?" in case we have three devices for downloading in three parts, but for now I will stick to the original question. Everything depends on it.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I double the @spikey_richie question.  What on earth could you need *THAT* for. :^P

Comment: @spikey_richie The question was just edited a few minutes ago, by the way (by the author, not me)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas See my comment ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *possible*...  However, more that likely, you would have to program your own torrent client, or modify an existing one to accomplish this.

The speed advantage of torrents comes from the fact you are downloading chunks of data from different sources, essentially at random, to build the larger file.

Some developers realized that people are downloading audio and video files and if they download the chunks in order, the media can be played as a stream when downloading.  If you found open source code for this type of torrent client, you could change the code to go in reverse order.

Comment: I will wait for more answers(since my priority is downloading that damn file), but since I am studying to be a good programmer, it would be a good project to customize stuff like that.. However am not up to such a task right now. I got to study lots. So I need to wait for answers. XD

Comment: @SubhamBurnwal Honestly, I wouldnt think its that hard to do.  In the source, there is a loop that is counting from 1 to the number of chunks in the torrent.  Simply change the code to start from the number of chunks and decrement to 1.

Comment: hell yeah(after a second thought). On my way to github

Comment: @SubhamBurnwal Lol.  I honestly dont know if its that easy, but I dont see why it wouldnt be.  Well be sure to upvote and accept if it works.

Comment: Done. It's qBittorrent.. and the source was not messy. Just had a bad time finding the right keywords to search for. What I couldn't do however.. was add an option in the menus that reverses the packets priority..So I ended up modifying the function which sets the priority in the general sequence.. so what I actually made was a version of qBit that downloads in reverse all the time. Gave that to my friend and he is downloading 2 big games from the tail..

Comment: @SubhamBurnwal cool.